# Passing data to view Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to pass row fetched from database to view from controller.

```
foreach ($usertable->result() as $note) {
    $note['title'];
    $this->load->view('note',$note);    
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Strictly, not the right way to send data to `view` (not inside `for loop`). This will load the `view` the numbers of time the loop runs. Put on more code. What you really want to do here ??

Comment: @ParagTyagi i want all the of$note data to passed as array into view(note)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly, not the right way to send data to `view` (not inside `for loop`). This will load the `view` the numbers of time the loop runs.

Enclosed all the **notes data** into a variable say via an array `data['notes']` and the now in view you can use `notes` variable for fetching data. 
Read **[docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html)** for more info.

**In controller:**

```
$data['notes'] = $usertable->result();
$this->load->view('note', $data);
```

**In view:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Note id</td>
    <td>title</td>
</tr>

<?php foreach($notes as $n) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $n->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $n->title; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following.

```
foreach ($usertable->result() as $note) {
    $note[]=$note;
}

$note['title'];
$this->load->view('note',$note);
```

Comment: I'm not down voting your answer but this will provide only last array value

Comment: foreach ($usertable->result() as $note) {
    $temp[]=$note;
}

$temp['title'];
$this->load->view('note',$temp); i think its cos i have paste same array you can try above.

Comment: you can define array before foreach like $temp=array();